# User card not loading properly

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, user-card

This happens once in a while. The user card displays numbers which are neither rep nor badge counts.

[image]

Version:0.1.20

Comment: Jon Skeet has some serious competition!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next update, thanks.